# ES,CQRS messaging flow

Tags: events, architecture, rabbitmq, cqrs, event-sourcing

I was trying to understanding ES+CQRS and tech stack can be used.
As per my understanding flow should be as below.

1. UI sends a request to Controller(HTTP Adapter)
2. Controller calls application service by passing Request Object as parameter.
3. Application Service creates Command from Request Object passed from controller.
4. Application Service pass this Command to Message Consumer.
5. Message Consumer publish Command to message broker(RabbitMQ)
6. Two Subscriber will be listening for above command
   a. One subscriber will generate Aggregate from eventStore using command
     and will apply command than generated event will be stored in event store.
   b. Another subscriber will be at VIEW end,that will populate data in view database/cache.

Kindly suggest my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Kindly suggest my understanding is correct

I think you've gotten a bit tangled in your middleware.

As a rule, CQRS means that the writes happen to one data model, and reads in another.  So the views aren't watching *commands*, they are watching the book of record.

So in the subscriber that actually processes the command, the command handler will load the current state from the book of record into memory, update the copy in memory according to the domain model, and then replace the state in the book of record with the updated version.

Having update the book of record, we can now trigger a refresh of the data model that backs the view; no business logic is run here, this is purely a transform of the data from the model we use for writes to the model we use for reads.

When we add event sourcing, this pattern is the same -- the distinction is that the data model we use for writes is a history of events.

> How atomicity is achieved in writing data in event store and writing data in VIEW Model?

It's not -- we don't try to make those two actions atomic.

> how do we handle if event is stored in EventStrore but System got crashed before we send event in Message Queue

The key idea is to realize that we typically build new views by reading events out of the event store; *not* by reading the events out of the message queue.  The events in the queue just tell us that an update is available.  In the absence of events appearing in the message queue, we can still poll the event store watching for updates.

Therefore, if the event store is unreachable, you just leave the stale copy of the view in place, and wait for the system to recover.

If the event store is reachable, but the message queue isn't, then you update the view (if necessary) on some predetermined schedule.

This is where the *eventual consistency* part comes in.  Given a successful write into the event store, we are promising that the effects of that write will be visible in a finite amount of time.

Comment: I am still not sure.How atomicity is achieved in writing data in event store and writing data in VIEW Model. What I have seen in blogs/article in Write Model CommandHanlders do following steps.
1. get Events from Event Store according to Command
2. Create Aggregate using events
3. Apply Command which generates events for that aggregate
4. Those events are
   a. Saved in event Store
   b. Event is sent in Message Queue to be consumed by Read Model
   Now a,b step is not atomic,how do we handle if event is stored in EventStrore but System got crashed before we send event in Message Queue.

Comment: The time from when an event is persisted to it being added to the queue is in most cases going to be measured in low milliseconds. It is therefore extremely unlikely to happen. But if it did - the version numbers of the aggregate and the read model will be out. Just replay the event(s) since the last read model update. You may find my post outlining a typical CQRS ES architecture helpful: [CQRS + Event Sourcing – A Step by Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

Comment: @Nishat some event databases such as GetEventStore provide both storage and a Publish/Subscribe mechanism, effectively making **a** and the publishing part of **b** atomic.

Comment: @Nishat the consuming part of **b** is more tricky. GetEventStore guarantees delivery if I remember correctly, but you still have to handle  read model update failures yourself.

Comment: @Nishat in any case, I don't think it's much in the spirit of CQRS or event-based systems to have (event emission, reception+processing by all subscribers) be atomic.